# unexpected EOF while looking for matching in sorting script

Tags: bash, unix

Can someone please assist with my script here, someone with fresh eyes, been working on it for a while. So:
At the end of the script I am trying to enable condition that if a user inputs a single letter 
as an input script  terminates/exits with "exit" message:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter file names (wild cards OK)'
read files
for input_source in $files ; do
    if test -f "$input_source" ; then 
        sort $input_source | uniq -c | head -10  
    elif "$input_source" = [a-z] ; then 
       exit
       echo 'Exit' 
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unterminated string literal:

```
elif "$input_source = [a-z] ; then  # where's the end?
```

Furthermore, once you fix that, it's still not valid. You'll probably want to use `test`, `[`, or `[[`, and even then, `=` won't do it. You probably want this:

```
elif [[ "$input_source" =~ "^[a-z]$" ]]; then
```

Comment: Still doesn't show the exit message. Same thing even if I tap a number

Comment: or it is better to use case ?

Comment: @Serg12: Oh, I didn't see that. Move the `echo` before the `exit`; `exit` makes it halt there and it never reaches the `echo`.